# Nuxt-Gmaps clusterStyle local icon

Tags: google-maps, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt-Gmaps and would like to add a local clusterStyle icon.

My code

```js
clusterStyle: [
  {
    url: "~/assets/img/map_cluster.svg",
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    textColor: "#000"
  }
],
```

The snippet is used here

```html
<GMap
    class="map"
    ref="gMap"
    language="en"
    :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}"
    :options=mapOptions
  >
```

I have found a workaround, when I put the icon in the `static` folder, but this isn't really best practice.

Comment: Whrlere is your snippet used here? Also, why not call a more classic path like `~/images/` or alike? `_nuxt` path is probably not something that you want to use here since it's the cache for the Nuxt environment.

Comment: I added the snippet where I used it and also changed the path to the correct path. This path also does not work, which is why I tried to use `_nuxt/`.

Comment: Can you load the svg itself? Last time I checked, you needed a loader for SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use `require` here

```js
clusterStyle: [
  {
    url: require("@/assets/img/map_cluster.svg"),
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    textColor: "#000"
  }
],
```

Comment: This is usually needed when the image is dynamic.

Comment: @kissu true, not sure why this is needed but it was the only way I managed to have it work, maybe the `@googlemaps/markerclusterer` that `nuxt-gmap` uses loads the image differently or something, didn't look into it